# FreeRTOS and Priority Inversion

Tags: rtos, freertos

Does FreeRTOS support priority inversion when configured for preemptive scheduling? I was unable to find this information from FreeRTOS websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Priority inversion is a feature of an application using an RTOS, not a feature of an RTOS, so no RTOS 'supports' priority inversion.  RTOSes do however support features such as priority inheritance and priority ceiling algorithms to minimise its effect.  Literature will tell you that these algorithms remove priority inversion, which is of course a nonsense, and an inversion would have to exist already in order to trigger the algorithm.  What the algorithms do do is make the inversion time bounded - best to just try and avoid the inversion in the first place though, if it is possible.

FreeRTOS mutexes (http://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html) use priority inheritance to time bound priority inversions.

Answer (score 1):

Freertos supports priority inheritance as a mechanism to tackle priority inversion. Please check the tasks.c file of freertos source code and refer the structure for task control block :

```
 #if ( configUSE_MUTEXES == 1 )
unsigned portBASE_TYPE uxBasePriority;                /* The priority last 
                                                         assigned to the task - 
                                                         used by the priority 
                                                         inheritance mechanism. */
```

The task control block for each task has a variable to save the actual (base) priority, in the event that the low priority task inherits priority of a high priority task - which is by the way - also waiting for the same resource as the low priority task.